# Github fork and edit button from an external site

Tags: github

Github has the very useful [*Fork this project and edit the file* button](https://github.com/blog/844-forking-with-the-edit-button):
[image: Github *edit* button]

I'd like to replicate the functionality on my own site. I want users to be able to click the button, and immediately be sent to Github, fork the project, and be sent to their forked repo's version of the file in an editable textbox. Click the *edit* button [here](https://github.com/schacon/why_i_love_github/blob/master/README.md) for an example of the functionality I am looking for.

I know that I can provide links to fork my repo from an external site like so:

```
https://github.com/user/repo/fork
```

So I tried doing this, but it did not work:

```
https://github.com/user/repo/fork/path/to/file
```

Is it possible to create a link or button in an external site which will fork and edit a file in Github?

#### Edit

I understand that it is impossible (and a bad idea) to *force* users to fork a repo (see [@sircapsalot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354482/github-fork-and-edit-button-from-an-external-site#answer-32354601)). However, I don't necessarily need users to be forced to fork the repo. I would settle for functionality which asks the user if they want to fork, and if they say yes, redirects them to their forked repo's version of the file in an editable textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL feature you're looking for is `edit` rather than `fork`:

```
https://github.com/user/repo/edit/path/to/file
```

This will prompt the user to fork the repo if they haven't and then open the file in edit mode in their fork.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force a user to fork a repository.  That link there is built into GitHub, so it's inherently "trusted" (same domain).

The best you can do, is do what [GitHub Badges](http://githubbadges.com) does and just direct the user to `https://github.com/user/repo/fork`.  But you **cannot** *force* the user to fork.

An example of why this would be a bad idea: say a malicious user creates a site that will fork ten-thousand repositories by force. That could make Github vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks.